# How to change ulimit in CentOS6

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos6

I am using `CentOS6.6` and trying to install `HDP2.2`

When I do:
`ulimit -Sn` Its value is `1024`

When I do:
`ulimit -Hn` Its value is `4096`

The recommended maximum number of open file descriptors is `10000`, or more.

I am trying to increase this value. I have checked several [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/how-can-i-increase-open-files-limit-for-all-processes) and trying to follow steps but not getting any success. I am looking some help to increase this value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS is different from RHEL5, you need to modify the file `/etc/security/limits.conf`, add the follow sentences to the end of file:

```
*           soft    nofile          655350
*           hard    nofile          655350
```

then, **relogin the system**(**very important**). 
Gook luck.

Comment: I have done the changes, but its still showing `1024`. Do I need to restart anything after said changes ?

Comment: I'm sorry I found a mistake on my answer, now I have modify it. Please cancel the last operation, and  try the new answer. Don't forget the to relogin the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, suppose if I want to set `10000` then I need to put the value `10000` instead of `655350` right?

Comment: Yes, you can have a try.